# Possible to override the current time in Rails development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app uses a lot of time-specific logic and models. In development, I will often change the time of my machine in order to more easily test and development my app. But, that has draw backs (e.g. parts of the internet stop working).

Is there any way to override what my Rails app things the 'current' time is? I'm not looking to change the time zone of the app. Nor am I looking to override or wrap every accessor to various Time methods. And lastly, I'm not looking to mess with the tests in my app (those are already wrapped in various timecop helpers and such).

It'd be great if, for example, I could set a time offset. So, if it is 5:00 PM EST, tell my rails app that the current time is actually 90 minutes less than the 'real' time. So if it was 5:00 PM EST, my app would read 3:30 PM EST.

This is likely not easily possibly, but is one of those things that would make my team's life infinitely easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [time interfaces in Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/time.c) are calling out to low-level C APIs like `localtime` and `gmtime`, so no. You would have to use something like [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop), or run it inside a VM.

Comment: VM is a great suggestion and exactly what I did. I set up my rails app in a Docker container, and used the ![libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) to override the time.

Comment: Sadly that did not end up working, libfaketime causes a segfault when used with Ruby. :(

Comment: @chrismanderson I'm not familiar with libfaketime, but I wouldn't expect Docker to be enough virtualization to succeed. You'll need something more like VirtualBox or similar.